# Laravel 10 - How to get full URL by route name from subdomain?

Tags: laravel, url, routes, subdomain

I have resource declared on my routes

```
// admin side
Route::resource('helpdesk', TicketController::class);
```

Then I have another route declared as a subdomain for client side

```
Route::domain('sobdomain.domain.com')->group(function () {
 Route::get('/', [ClientController::class, 'index'])->name('clientHome');
});
```

// Here I want to get the URL from 'helpdesk.show' but it will return the current URL which is 'sobdomain.domain.com' instead of 'domain.com'

```
// ClientController index function
public function index()
{
  // This will return sobdomain.domain.com/helpdesk/1 instead of domain.com/helpdesk/1
  dd(route('helpdesk.show',1))
}
```

I already tried `route('helpdesk.show',1)` but this will return 'sobdomain.domain.com/helpdesk/1'.

What I wanted to get is 'domain.com/helpdesk/1'

Comment: Why not just use a [PHP string replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)? `str_replace('sobdomain.', '', route('helpdesk.show', 1))`. If `sobdoamin` is known (i.e. not dynamic), then you can reliably remove it from the output of `route()`.

Comment: Can you try to put the `Route::domain` before other routes ? look at documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing